# Having trouble understanding links in laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a problem with link_to_action in laravel 4

In laravel 3 i would show a link like

```php
{{ HTML::link_to_action('user/create', 'Create User') }}
```

But since I've switched to laravel 4 I'm creating my controllers like this UserController but when I try to use the HTML

```php
{{ HTML::linkAction('user/create', 'Create User') }}
```

It gives me and error that action doesn't exist even though there's a method named create.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

And here's my controller

```php
<?php

class UserController extends \BaseController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```php
// L3
{{ HTML::link_to_action('user@create', 'Create User') }}

// L4
{{ HTML::linkAction('UserController@create', 'Create User') }}
```

edit:

```php
// I think you missed that entry in your routes.php
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

Comment: Well I tried that and it seemed to work, but still giving errors

Comment: do You have that entry in your routes.php? **Route::resource('user', 'UserController');**

Comment: Yes I do but when I try to test update or destroy it gives error

Comment: I'm trying to use the except array for the http verbs that take a parameter so that I can run reg expr on the id

Comment: please update your question with new question, new problem and new code as now you are asking about another problem